# Matlab--Multi dimensional dot product array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave, vectorization

I have two arrays both of which contain several 3x1 vectors. The arrays are different dimensions. I am trying to creat an array that holds the dot product for every combo without using (for) loops but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Would appreciate any thoughts tips or tricks

```
a = 5;
b = 6;
c = 10;

% 2 arrays
% uno is 3xAxB
% dos is 3xC
uno = rand(3, a, b);
dos = rand(3, c);

% Array to hold all the dot products
tres = zeros(a, b, c)

for m = 1:a
    for n = 1:b
        for p = 1:c
            u = uno(:,m, n);
            d = dos(:,p);
            tres(m, n, p) = u'*d
        end
    end
end

% WHY CAN I NOT DO THIS???
% How do I get all the dot products quickly and via vectorization?
% x = 1:a
% y = 1:b
% z = 1:c
% 
% tres(x, y, z) = uno(:,x, y)'*dos(:,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for MATLAB and Octave:

```
tres=reshape(reshape(uno,3,[]).' * dos, a,b,c);
```

In the case of Octave you can write:

```
tres=reshape((dos.' * uno).',a,b,c);
```

*The first solution is more cheaper because it includes only one transpose.

Essentially we want to reduce a series of *vector-vector* (dot) operations to a *vector-matrix* or to a *matrix-matrix* operation. All we need is to reshape/transpose/permute arrays to have compatible dimensions. The vectors that you want to multiply are arranged as columns of  pages and pages are concatenated to form a 3D array. We can reshape the array so that instead of pages concatenated along the third dimension they are concatenated horizontally. So an array of size `[3 5 6]` can be reshaped to a matrix of size `[ 3 30]` .Now size of the reshaped array is compatible with the size of  `dos` so we can use matrix multiplication and the result can be reshaped back to the original dimension. Here a series of *vector-vector* operations is reduced to a ,more efficient, *matrix-matrix* operation.

Comment: THANK YOU. it works great. Can you/someone explain why it works/what it is doing

Comment: @JesseRubin Explanations added.